# On hover tooltip on mouse hover at geom_label_repel() label

Tags: r, shiny, hover, tooltip, dashboard

My plots in shiny dashboard use `geom_label_repel()` to repel overlapped labels.

I want to show information on mouse hover over this labels - brand name.

Plotly package can`t support` geom_label_repel()` labels, so I am using this snippet to solve:

https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/16220

My plots are like this:

```
ggplot(reactive1(), aes(wave, value, group = brand, color = brand)) +
               geom_point() +
               geom_path() +
               geom_label_repel(reactive1(),
                                mapping=aes(wave, value, group = brand, color = brand, label = sig),
                                ...
)


ggplot(reactive2(), aes(wave, value, group = brand, color = brand)) +
               geom_point() +
               geom_path() +
               geom_label_repel(reactive2(),
                                mapping=aes(wave, value, group = brand, color = brand, label = sig),
                                ...
)
```

and so on...

ui.R

```
div(
 style = "position:relative",

 withSpinner(
  plotOutput("plot_x",
   height = "600px", 
   hover = hoverOpts(id = "plot_hover", delay = 50)
  ),
                                                                                      
 ),
uiOutput("dynamic")
)
```

each plot have own reactive dataset in server.R.

```
     reactive1 <-  reactive({
          
          current_data_list <- cb_a
          
          combo_name <- "cb_a"
          
          
          res <- calculate_data(input, output, session, current_data_list, combo_name)
          res
          
     })
```

res =
| wave | brand | value | sig  |
| ---- | ----- | ----- | ---- |
| Cl 1 | Cl 2  | Cl 3  | Cl 4 |

so snippet works ok with

```
     output$dynamic <- renderUI({
          renderUI({
               hover <- input$plot_hover
               point <- nearPoints(reactive1(), hover, threshold = 5, maxpoints = 1, addDist = TRUE)
.
.
.
```

My main problem is tooltip shown over geom_point() hover. I need over geom_label_repel() label hover.

My second problem is reactive datasets. How to pass correct reactive2() dataset into output$dynamic nearPoints() for plot_x2?

Tryed

```
output$plot_x <-   renderPlot({
 gglpot()
 current_plot <- reactive1()
})
```

and

```
     output$dynamic <- renderUI({
          renderUI({
               hover <- input$plot_hover
               point <- nearPoints(current_plot, hover, threshold = 5, maxpoints = 1, addDist = TRUE)
```

with no effect

and tryed a plotly package over ggplot(). With "geom_label_repel() is not supported" error.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Snippet is reproducible. I just need set it on correct reactive dataset and tooltip shown on  geom_label_repel() instead  geom_point()